# positional method instead of selector in jquery event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm catching a custom event like this:

```
$("#my_div").on("custom_event", ".some_class:first", function...
```

That is working fine. The thing is that because [jQuery 3.4 is deprecating](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/) `:first` selector (among others), I would like to do something like

```
$("#my_div").on("custom_event", $(".some_class").first(), function...
```

But that doesn't work because [the selector parameter must be a string](https://api.jquery.com/on/). In my case the event is captured on second, third, etc. besides the first one. I need to only be captured on first.

How can I update the code? I would like to avoid and if statement to test the position, is there a way to make it work like before?

Comment: What about 
$("#my_div").children(".some_class").first().on("click", function..
?

Comment: or `$("#my_div .some_class").eq(0).on("click", function...`

Comment: Form the page you linked to _" Keep in mind we will still support the positional methods, such as .first, .last, and .eq. Anything you can do with positional selectors, you can do with positional methods instead. They perform better anyway."_

Comment: You can't use `.first()` or `.eq()` in `.on()`. It must be a Selector: *A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.*

Comment: @VSMent that looks good

Comment: @johnSmith I also like this approach

Comment: @Twisty yes, I'm aware of that, I even stated it in my question

Comment: @MatíasCánepa caught that, thanks. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [':first-child'](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) instead.

```
$("#my_div .some_class:first-child").on("custom_event", function(){
   // code 
)};
```

if you are manipulating DOM (create elements dynamically) you just have to use .on() on something that is there from start, the selector will not change, for example:

```
$(document).on('custom_event', "#my_div .some_class:first-child",function(){
  // code
})
```

It makes sense that jquery changed it so it equaly matches the css pseudo-selectors.

Comment: If `.some_class` are dynamically created elements, that will not work. If those are static... well. OP just does useless delegations (maybe!)

Comment: that is no problem if you use .on() on something that is there from beginning, look at my update

Comment: @johnSmith given some nuances in my code, the eq() version work as intended, also de first() version as commented by VSMent

Answer (score 1):

First, that deprecation appears in the jQuery [version 3.4.0 release notice](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/) dated of april 10th, 2019.

They say:

> Anything you can do with positional selectors, you can do with positional methods instead. They perform better anyway.

Okay... **Sadly**, the documentation lacks an explanation on possible code replacement/upgrade about the use of this useful pseudo-selector in the delegation scenario you point out.

Now, that only is a [deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)... not a removal notice. So you don't actually have to upgrade your code for now. The latest jQuery version is [3.5.1](https://blog.jquery.com/2020/05/04/jquery-3-5-1-released-fixing-a-regression/) (may 4th, 2020) and there was no removal of `:first` and similar pseudo-selectors yet.

I guess that if you want to make it overkill anyway to be *future-proof*, this would give an equivalent result:

```
$("#my_div").on("custom_event", function(e){
  let $this = $(e.target).closest("#my_div").find(".some_class").eq(0)
  
  $this.doSomethingElseHere()
  //...
})
```

That is making the event handler attached to `#my_div` and `$this` being the delegated element.

***I agree that's ugly!*** So I would not do that (lol). It's only is to point out there always will be another way to do it... And for now, that is the best I can think of considering what we have in the not yet *deprecated* toolset.

> is there a way to make it work like before?

As of november 2020, you can use the latest jQuery version and use that `:first` pseudo-selector in delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `:first-of-type` or `:nth-child(1)` selector? Because I believe that's what you're supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

AS both `:first()` and `:eq()` will be deprecated, you could filter later.

```
$("#my_div").on("custom_event", ".some_class", function(e){
  var target = $(this).parent().children().first();
});
```

You may consider using `.closest()` and `.find()` in case they are not direct parent or child nodes.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container").on("click", ".item", function(e) {
    var target = $(this).closest(".container").find(".item").first();
    console.log(target.text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:eq` is in the deprecation list along with `:first` in the [3.4.0 release note](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/) OP mentionned... ;)